# attaching file to note - freshdesk

Tags: laravel, multipartform-data, ticket-system, freshdesk

I am trying to send attachment to a ticket using the API making sure it is sent multipart/form-data however I am not able to do so.The API docs doesn't show an example for syntax it should be sent with so I can't figure it how to do so.
How data is sent:

```
Input::all();
      $json = json_encode(
          array(
                "helpdesk_note" => array(
                "body" => Input::get('reply'),
                "user_id" => $requester_id,
                "private" => true,
                "attachments" => array(
                    Input::get('photo')                
                )
            )
        )
      );

    $this->curlWrap("tickets/".$ticket_id."/conversations/note.json", $json, "POST");
```

Comment: So... what is not working?

Comment: @PatrickReck whena dding the attachments field, nothing is sent. When I remove it, the comment is sent successfully

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong, please note the attachments need to be in a multipart/form-data, and you are trying to pass the body as JSON. Fresh desk don't allow that.

Please read this [RFC1867](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1867.html) this and you can do it! Pay attention in section 6. Examples.

You need put your body in this format:

```
    Content-type: multipart/form-data, boundary=AaB03x

    --AaB03x
    content-disposition: form-data; name="helpdesk_note[body]"

    Your message here.
    --AaB03x
    content-disposition: form-data; name="helpdesk_note[attachments][][resource]"; filename="fileSomeName.jpg"
    Content-Type: image/jpeg

     ... contents of fileSomeName.jpg here ...
    --AaB03x--
```

You also need to set these headers:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
Content-Length: 2632
```

Content-Length need to be the exact size of all body.